# What pre-requisites are there for crafting Stalhrim items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

No massive spoilers, but to be safe....:

> I've been playing the excellent Dragonborn expansion and have just done "the quest" where I am supposedly allowed to use Stalhrim, or have been granted permission to use the forge in Skaal village to make stuff with it - however I don't know what I am supposed to do - there is no option at the blacksmith at either the forge, or with the guy who runs it, but I am carrying 5x of what looks more stalhrim ore.

My assumption is that I either need to do something to turn the ore into ingots (Smelter doesn't give me any options, so I feel this is less likely), or, I need to reach a particular level in Smithing - I'm playing as a brand new character and only level 22 currently and my smithing skill is in the mid 50s

Can anyone shed any light on the exact requirements? I feel like I've done a fair chunk of the DLC already so I'd quite like to use some of the unique items on what remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It requires the perk ebony Smithing. It does not need to be smelted; it is used as-is.

Comment: Thank you. I went back to a previous autosave and replayed the end of the quest and the blacksmith in Skaal village tells you "If you can craft Ebony items, you can craft Stalhrim items" (not in those exact words....) - I was too impatient to walk to the forge and didn't listen :)